# Creating Java Class Files With The Help Of Java ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am working on a project where I am trying to automate the process of writing Java code, and I have created a compiler with the help of JAVA Asm which creates byte code but in textual form, following is an example of my output:

```
    public class prolog/Jprolog 
    {
    public <init>()V
    L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
    L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lprolog/Jprolog; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
    public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "Hello, Jprolog Print command"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    L1
    LINENUMBER 9 L1
    RETURN
    L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
    }
```

Now I want to test this on java compiler, however it won't accept the code. Now my question is how do I convert this into a legal class file (i.e. .class file) so that I can run it directly on java compiler.

Comment: What do you mean with “with the help of JAVA Asm”? Are you referring to the [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/)? This library does already provide you with [a method to get the byte code](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#toByteArray--) in the class file format. In fact, generating the textual output of your question is harder than getting the byte code.

Comment: @Holger  Yes I am talking about ASM library. However the method you mentioned solved my problem. But since I am new to ASM could you please give me an example. Take an example of printing "Hello World" string.

Comment: How did you generate the code you’ve posted in your question?

Comment: @Holger I have created a tool in prolog! But now I need to convert the above mentioned code into .class file so that I can run that class file on java compiler. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Try going through [the tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html). Further, [ASMifier](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q10) is a great way to generate your own example code, based on a class template of your own, to be (re)generated.